# Javascript | Heap out of memory server side

Tags: javascript, jenkins, heap-memory

I am getting error "*Javascript | Heap out of memory*" exeption when running our build in jenkins. We had similar issue in local and by setting node --max-old-space-size=8192 we have solved the issue. How do we get rid of the same on the server side?

Comment: if you have package.json file than set below option

"scripts": {
  "start": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js ,
}

Comment: okay. will try that out. does it need to have in particular app.js in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Package.json file than try below.
May be it will solve your problem.

```
"scripts": { "start": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js" }
```

You have to change other options in "start" as per your need.

For example, you can use your own file instead of app.js, or
you can also just set the command like below without any file name.

```
"scripts": { "start": "node --max-old-space-size=8192" }
```

`--max-old-space-size` is used for setting the "old space" memory limit, which means garbage collection or heap where all javascript objects are available. So to solve the issue of memory, you have to increase the limit of memory. For example, if your server machine has 2 GB of memory, than you can set `--max-old-space-size` to around 1.5 GB, so other memory is available to perform other tasks.

You can also use the below package if you are using NodeJS before version 8.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: When we set the --max-old-spae-size does it allocate certain amount of memory in the virtual machines ROM? We are deploying in cloud servers and probably the server does not have much of memory due to which it is failing?

Comment: @MAINAKBHATTACHARYA Please see answer for more information.
i updated my answer.
if my answer is solved your problem and helpful for you than please accept it.